# How to make Retrofit class

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to use the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
 library to make api requests to the [Riot API](https://developer.riotgames.com)
and an example request returns json that looks like this:

```
{"dyrus":{"id":5908,"name":"Dyrus","profileIconId":752,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1431126576000}}
```

Notice the object `dyrus` has multiple sub properties and I want to get the id property. The problem I am having is I don't want to just look up the id for `dyrus` but for other players as well. When I look up other players the name of the object changes depending on the name I look up. For example here is another example request:

```
{"theoddone":{"id":60783,"name":"TheOddOne","profileIconId":752,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1431327360000}}
```

`theoddone` is now the name of the object. How do I make a retrofit class that dynamically changes the name of the object depending on the person being searched. Or how do I access the id property? My class looks like this right now but does not work:

```
public class Summoner {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int profileIconId;
    private int summonerLevel;
    private int revisionDate;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The profileIconId
     */
    public int getProfileIconId() {
        return profileIconId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param profileIconId
     * The profileIconId
     */
    public void setProfileIconId(int profileIconId) {
        this.profileIconId = profileIconId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The summonerLevel
     */
    public int getSummonerLevel() {
        return summonerLevel;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param summonerLevel
     * The summonerLevel
     */
    public void setSummonerLevel(int summonerLevel) {
        this.summonerLevel = summonerLevel;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The revisionDate
     */
    public int getRevisionDate() {
        return revisionDate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param revisionDate
     * The revisionDate
     */
    public void setRevisionDate(int revisionDate) {
        this.revisionDate = revisionDate;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need to see any other part of how I am using retrofit. Thanks in advance.

Interface:

```
public interface SummonerId {

    @GET("/api/lol/{region}/v1.4/summoner/by-name/{summonerName}")
    void summoner(
      @Path("region") String region,
      @Path("summonerName") String summonerName,
      @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
      Callback<Summoner> cb
    );

}
```

Code in the oncreate method of my activity:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint("https://na.api.pvp.net")
            .build();

SummonerId service = restAdapter.create(SummonerId.class);

service.summoner("na", "dyrus", "MY API KEY", new Callback<Summoner>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Summoner summoner, Response response) {
        //summoner.getId() == null
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

When I run the code it successfully connects to the server and gets the right json, but does not properly put it into the class.

Comment: Looks like you're not getting a `Summoner` but something like `SommonerWrapper` with a variable of type `Summoner` named according to the summoner. That variable name looks like a major hiccup. You'll need a custom TypeAdapter from Gson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got it. Took me a long time though.

So first you have to create a custom TypeAdapterFactory like the following class:

```
public class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    String name;

    public ItemTypeAdapterFactory(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has(name) && jsonObject.get(name).isJsonObject())
                    {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get(name);
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

For your usage you can actually just copy and paste that but please try and understand what happens.

Next you will have to implement a custom GsonBuilder like follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory("dyrus")).create();
```

**The important part is the "dyrus" which you can replace with the name you are looking for.**

Next add the gsonbuilder to your restadapter:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint("your endpoint")
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                    .build();
```

Use the following method in your connection interface:

```
public void getCurrentUser(Callback<Summoner> response);
```

And receive your POJO response as follows:

```
    ConnectionInterface connectionInterface = restAdapter.create(**ConnectionInterface.class**);
    connectionInterface.getCurrentUser(new Callback<Summoner>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Summoner response, Response response2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("Response", error.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

};

**Your POJO class is correct you can name it anything you want a long as the variables retain their names. You can call the class UserPOJO for clarity and just rename all instances of Summoner to UserPojo**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Got it to work thank you. One question though. Do I need to make a new 'RestAdapter' for every request? If not how do I make another request using the same adapter. Thanks

Comment: mmm you might be able to get the search string externally into the AdapterFactory but further than that I have no idea.